# WPF TimePicker dropdown intervals

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker, xceed-plus-edition

I have a `TimePicker` declared in my XAML view:

```
<xctk:TimePicker Grid.Column="5" Value="{Binding TimeFrame}" StartTime="00:00:0" EndTime="23:59:0" Format="Custom" FormatString="HH:mm" Margin="3 3 3 0" MinWidth="100"/>
```

Which binds to this `TimeFrame` method in my view model class:

```
private DateTime _timeFrame;
public DateTime TimeFrame
{
    get { return _timeFrame; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _timeFrame)
        {
            _timeFrame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeFrame");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to limit the dropdown to only 30 min intervals e.g. 07:00:00, 07:30:00 08:00:00 08:30:00 etc. ? I've tried setting `TimeInterval` property shown at https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/TimePicker to `TimeInterval="30"`, but this seems to just only keep 00:00:00 in the dropdown.

I could make my own custom user control to do this, but it would be nice to make it work with this toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've just found the issue.

You need to use full `HH:mm:ss` format:

```
TimeInterval="00:30:00"
```

Instead of:

```
TimeInterval="30"
```